# Rotation between 2 points facing away when standing at back while facing towards while standing infront (pics)

Tags: c++11

With this little piece of code I've made it possible to rotate the 'monster' towards the avatar but if the avatar is behind the 'monster', the 'monster' is facing away from the avatar. (Pic's below)

Note: the white numbers are the value of `m_RotationAngle`

```
DOUBLE2 mousePos = GAME_ENGINE->GetMousePosition();

double xDiff = m_ActPtr->GetPosition().x - mousePos.x;
double yDiff = m_ActPtr->GetPosition().y - mousePos.y;
m_RotationAngle = atan(yDiff, xDiff);
m_ActPtr->SetAngle(m_RotationAngle);
```

[image: Avatar standing behind monsters][image: Avatar standing infront of monsters]

I've tried to fix it with:

```
if (diff.x < 0)
{
    m_RotationAngle = -atan(diff.y / diff.x);
    //also tried following but gave and error:
    //m_RotationAngle = tan(diff.y / diff.x);
}
else
{
    m_RotationAngle = atan(diff.y / diff.x);
}
```

But this gave the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`atan2(yDiff, xDiff);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) which computes the arc tangent of yDiff/xDiff using the signs of arguments to determine the correct quadrant, instead of [atan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan) (which also require only one parameter).

Be aware that the result is in the range [-π ; +π] radians, not degrees.